# Simple idea to simplify $(z_1^2+z_2^2)^{10}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

is the simple idea to simplify $(z_1^2+z_2^2)^{10}$ ?
when $$z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}\\z_1-z_2=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac12 i\\z_1z_2=1+i$$Itried to rewrite $$z_1^2+z_2^2=(z_1-z_2)^2+2z_1z_2\\=(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac12 i)^2+2(1+i)\\=\frac34-\frac14+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i+2+2i$$ but for power of 10 ...it is not good.

may be as imple method to simplify this ?  thanks in advance .

Comment: Perhaps try writing what you obtained there in the form $re^{i\theta}$. Haven't tried it, but if you could, it may be easy to proceed